# Javascript While Loops and Outputting data each time

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am a newbie to JS and I am trying to get the while loop to 
output a string each time it iterates through the loop. But I keep getting
the final text string and not the collection of strings I need.

I am looking to see what the values of British Pound Sterling and US 
Dollars are through a series of runs through the loop.

In the big picture I am trying to find out the values of BSP and USD when 
they are almost equal. If I print out the values each time through the 
loop I can then look at the output and see when the pairs were almost equal.

I need this because I have two friends (one lives in England and one lives 
in the United States) and they want to split their profits equally between 
them using each person's own currency evaluations. i.e. If the profit is 
400 pounds what would be an equal share among them in their own 
currencies? Splitting up the money by pounds would unfairly give the US 
friend more spending dollars than the friend in England (200 pounds = 
281.60 USD at current exchange rates)

```
<hmtl>
<head></head>
<body>

<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Revenue" id="textEntered">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Exchange Rate" id="rateEntered">
    <button id="myButton">Calculate</button>

    <p id="output">Replace text here</p>
</div>

    <script type=text/javascript>
        document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function (){

        var revenueInput = document.getElementById("textEntered").value;
        var rate = document.getElementById("rateEntered").value;

        revenueInput = revenueInput/2; //Split the money equally to begin
        var revenueSplit = revenueInput;
        var bsp = revenueInput;
        var usd = revenueInput * rate;
        var difference = usd - revenueSplit;
        var text = "";
        var i = 0;

    /* Now we need to add 1 pound to the bsp while at the same time
       take away "rate" from the usd */

        while ( i < difference && usd >= revenueSplit) {
            bsp++;
            usd = usd - rate;
            text = "British Pound is " + bsp + " and the USD is " + usd;
            i++;
        }

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your output `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += text;` should be in `while` loop, **OR** you should add to the string in the loop: `text += "British Pound is " + bsp + " and the USD is " + usd;` Notice the `+=` operator. It adds to already existing value

Comment: or do `text +=` instead of `text =`. Also add a `<br>` to prevent it all merging together

Comment: Thanks Ludovit Mydla and charlietfl !! Worked like a charm!

Comment: It isn't unfair for one of them to get £200 and the other one $281, because they're worth the same amount. That's what an exchange rate means.

Comment: Ben West - I understand where you're coming from, but the reality is that the spending values are different. The real buying power is unequal and therefore they want to divi it up this way. In any case, it was a nice challenge for me to come up with a function that accomplishes this for them.